# How do I remove the Twitter icon from indicator-messages?

Tags: indicator, uninstall, messaging-menu, twitter

Ubuntu 12.10 When I click Envelope (indicator-messages) the icons for Twitter, Майл.ру, Google+ and Unity-mail are appears.

1) Problem
I need only Unity-mail linked with my Google-mail account, but I needn't Google+, Twitter and Майл.ру. It's impossible to remove these icons from Envelope.

2) I tried to remove Twitter, Google+ and Майл.ру lens from OS using Synaptic packages manager. These packages are removed, but it appears on Envelope, and is runs when I click on indicator-messages menu.

!!! Please dont't propose to remove Envelope. I don't want to remove Envelope, but only Twitter, Майл.ру, Google+ icons from indicator-messages list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove unneeded indicators from the Messaging Indicator you can:

a) Delete or move somewhere items from `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/` (sudo is needed).

b) Non-destructive way: make symlinks to each undesired item in the blacklist folder `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/` (you should create it beforehand if it is absent). For example, to remove Gwibber (Twitter client) you should run in terminal:

```
ln -s /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/gwibber.indicator ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/gwibber.indicator
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I find solution of my problem here: http://askubuntu.com/a/271087/98478