# How to remove leftover unity-webapps-facebookmessenger icons?

Tags: 12.04, unity, webapps, facebook

I have uninstalled unity-webapps-facebookmessenger but I have left over launcher icons in the dash and message menu.  I have removed the facebook.com entry from allowed webapps domains in dconf-editor.

How can I get rid of this annoying facebook icon in my message menu?

Comment: Have you right clicked on it and selected "Unlock from Launcher"?

Comment: Hi, its not on the launcher, its in the dash, but the annoying part is the message menu

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/204436/44179) answer?

Comment: Yes, have already uninstalled it.  Thats the problem really.

Comment: So you used the Software Center or D-conf?

Comment: I see what you are saying, I removed the desktop file from .local/share/applications and it worked thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently when you uninstall the webapp package from Software Center it doesn't delete the icons. So you just need to go to "~/.local/share/applications" and delete the file for facebook "facebookfacebookcom.desktop" or any other webapp.